# Correctly Route 2 Newtorks

Tags: networking, dhcp, iptables

I am currently running Pidora and I have configured it so that dhcpd hands out an IP address to devices connected via Ethernet on a network of 192.168.2.1 whilst it (the Pi) obtains a static IP from my wireless router on the netowkr adress of 192.168.1.1

I have allowed IP v4 forwarding and ran the following commands

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE  
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT  
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT
```

I can now access the wider web through my Pi, i.e when connected to the ethernet the device can get to the outside world.

My issue is that I cannot reach any device on the ethernet from an device connected to my router.

The ethernet network address is 192.168.2.1 with gate way 192.168.2.0. My wireless router hands out address in the range 192.168.1.X

If I attempt to ping from a device on my wireless with an IP such as 192.168.1.105 to an address like 192.168.2.85 I get no response.

I am unsure of the correct networking configuration to get the networks to reach each other, any help is greatly appreciated.

:-)

Answer (score 1):

Been on this for a couple of days and I have now realised I needed to set up a route to the network on my Pi from my Wireless router.

Logged in to "usual" home network address 192.168.1.1 and added a route rule here to map any IP on that network to any IP on my Pis network (192.168.2.0)